# How to resolve HBase query data by row like oracle/mysql in(row1,row2,row3...)

Tags: java, database, hadoop, hbase

at oracle/mysql we usually query record use

```
select * from test t where t.id in(1001,1002,1003);
```

but hbase has no that api to select data,only can 
use scan(startRow) and endRow;

who have reolve this question,or have method to do this. 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for HBase as a replacement for an RDBMS than don't. HBase is much more limited in the way you can query data.

In any event if your row key in HBase is id you can do the query you mentioned as 3 GETs by key

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with Arnon... HBase is not really an RDBMS replacement.

To get some of the query functionality you are looking for, you should consider using [Hive](http://hive.apache.org/), which is a almost-SQL implementation that runs over data in Hadoop or HBase.

When interacting with HBase with Java like you mention in your question, you can use a [filter](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/package-summary.html), specifically the [`ValueFilter`](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/ValueFilter.html), to filter out values. This will make it so only rows that match the criterion to be returned. Take a look at the [hbase reference guide on filters](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#client.filter) to learn more on how to implement this.